# Kusto/Azure Data Explorer - How can I partition an external table using a timespan field?

Tags: azure, csv, datetime, timespan, azure-data-explorer

Hoping someone can help..
I am new to Kusto and have to get an external table reading data from an Azure Blob storage account working, but the one table I have is unique in that the data for the timestamp column is split into 2 separate columns , i.e. LogDate and LogTime (see script below).

My data is stored in the following structure in the Azure Storage account container (container is named "employeedata", for example):
{employeename}/{year}/{month}/{day}/{hour}/{minute}.csv, in a simple CSV format.

I know the CSV is good because if I import it into a normal Kusto table, it works perfectly.

My KQL script for the external table creation looks as follows:

```
.create-or-alter external table EmpLogs (Employee: string, LogDate: datetime, LogTime:timestamp) 
kind=blob 
partition by (EmployeeName:string = Employee, yyyy:datetime = startofday(LogDate), MM:datetime = startofday(LogDate), dd:datetime = startofday(LogDate), HH:datetime = todatetime(LogTime), mm:datetime = todatetime(LogTime))
pathformat = (EmployeeName "/" datetime_pattern("yyyy", yyyy) "/" datetime_pattern("MM", MM) "/" datetime_pattern("dd", dd) "/" substring(HH, 0, 2) "/" substring(mm, 3, 2) ".csv")
dataformat=csv 
( 
    h@'************************' 
) 
with (folder="EmployeeInfo", includeHeaders="All")
```

I am getting the error below constantly, which is not very helpful (redacted from full error, basically comes down to the fact there is a syntax error somewhere):

Syntax error: Query could not be parsed: {
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest_SyntaxError",
"message": "Request is invalid and cannot be executed.",
"@type": "Kusto.Data.Exceptions.SyntaxException",
"@message": "Syntax error: Query could not be parsed: . Query: '.create-or-alter external table ........

I know the `todatetime()` function works on timespan's, I tested it with another table and it created a date similar to the following: 0001-01-01 20:18:00.0000000.

I have tried using the bin() function on the timestamp/LogTime columns, but the same error as above, and even tried importing the time value as a string and doing some string manipulation on it, no luck. Getting the same syntax error.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there's no way to define an external table partition based on more than one column. If your dataset timestamp is splitted between two columns: `LogDate:datetime` and `LogTime:timestamp`, then the best you can do is use virtual column for the partition by time:

```
.create-or-alter external table EmpLogs(Employee: string, LogDate:datetime, LogTime:timespan) 
kind=blob 
partition by (EmployeeName:string = Employee, PartitionDate:datetime)
pathformat = (EmployeeName "/" datetime_pattern("yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm", PartitionDate))
dataformat=csv 
( 
    //h@'************************'
) 
with (folder="EmployeeInfo", includeHeaders="All")
```

Now, you can filter by the virtual column and fine tune using `LogTime`:

```
external_table("EmpLogs")
| where Employee in ("John Doe", ...)
| where PartitionDate between(datetime(2020-01-01 10:00:00) .. datetime(2020-01-01 11:00:00))
| where LogTime ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the advice I needed. Seems to work fine for my scenario!!